# How show last 10 data stored in data base in table view?

Tags: iphone, database, uitableview, nsdata

I have data base in which i am storing source address,destination address and category. Now i want to show only last 10 data stored in that data base on table view. I am using this code for retrieving data form data base...

```
 -(void) openDB {

listOfStudents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK) {
    const char *sql = "select * from Places";
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    int rtnVal = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL);
    if( rtnVal == SQLITE_OK) {
        while (sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            Places_data *pd_object = [[[Places_data alloc] init] autorelease];
            pd_object.place_id = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0);
            pd_object.start_add = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1)];
            pd_object.end_add = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 2)];
            pd_object.strcategroy =  [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 3)];

            [self.listOfStudents addObject:pd_object];
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
}
sqlite3_close(db);
```

}

Now what i do changes in above code show that it show only last 10 results in table view?

Answer (score 1):

you can use following query which will fetch only last 10 records only.

```
const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM Places order by rowid desc limit 10";
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends what does it mean "last"? If you have any autoincrement id colunm, then you propably mean "last inserted" or those with largest id. In your case, where you are using sqlite, you could use something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Places ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Where `Id` is your autoincrement column name. The statement will select all entries from table `Places`, then order it by `Id` descending and use just first 10 results.

In some other databases you could try also:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Places ORDER BY Id DESC;
```

But **note** that not all database systems support the TOP clause.

Hope it solves your problem.